# Problems with SET and SETLOCAL

Tags: batch-file

Just to make this clear, I have looked at the other questions on this subject, but they either don't address this issue, or more often don't fix it.

I suspect the issue is to do with nested FOR loops and where to put SETLOCAL.

What I have is a function to check that a file has been modified since a certain time:

```
:CheckCopied result directory filename since -- returns whether the file has been modified in the time since 'since'
::                      -- result    [out]    - 0=FAIL, 1=SUCCESS
::                      -- directory [in]     - target directory
::                      -- filename [in]      - target filename
::                      -- since [in]         - the time the script started
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set directory=%~2
set filename=%~3
set since=%~4

ECHO.CheckCopied directory="%directory%", filename=%filename%, since=%since%

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%d IN ('echo ^| dir "%directory%" ^| find "%filename%"') DO  (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%h IN ('echo %%e') DO (
        ECHO Hours:  %since:~0,2%  vs  %%h
        ECHO Minutes:  %since:~3,2%  vs  %%i
        SET hours=!since:~0,2!
        SET minutes=%since:~3,2%
        ECHO hours=%hours%   minutes=%minutes%
        SET /A minutesSince=60*hours+minutes
        ECHO %minutesSince%
        SET hours=%%h
        SET minutes=%%i
        ECHO hours=%hours%   minutes=%minutes%
    )
)

EXIT /b
```

This outputs:

```
CheckCopied directory="<my directory>" filename=<my filename> since=15:18:34.98
Hours:  15  vs  15
Minutes:  18  vs  11
hours=  minutes=
ECHO is off.
hours=  minutes=
```

So the "SET hours=!since:~0,2!" seems not to work.

I have tried:

```
SET hours=!since:~0,2!
SET hours=%since:~0,2%
SET /A hours=!since:~0,2!
Every combination I could think of of SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and ENDLOCAL
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with SETLOCAL, but I can't find the magic combination...

**EDIT:**

Many thanks to jeb, below.  I've redone the function as per his advice here:

```
:CheckCopied result directory filename since -- returns whether the file has been modified in the last 5 minutes
::                      -- result    [out]    - 0=FAIL, 1=SUCCESS
::                      -- directory [in]     - target directory
::                      -- filename [in]      - target filename
::                      -- since [in]         - the time the script started
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set directory=%~2
set filename=%~3
set since=%~4

ECHO.CheckCopied directory="%directory%", filename=%filename%, since=%since%

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%d IN ('echo ^| dir "%directory%" ^| find "%filename%"') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%h IN ('echo %%e') DO (
        ECHO Hours:  %since:~0,2%  vs  %%h
        ECHO Minutes:  %since:~3,2%  vs  %%i
        SET hours=!since:~0,2!
        SET minutes=!since:~3,2!
        ECHO hours=!hours!   minutes=!minutes!
        SET /A minutesSince=60*hours+minutes
        ECHO !minutesSince!
        SET /A hoursx=%%h
        SET /A minutesx=%%i
        ECHO hours=!hoursx!   minutes=!minutesx!
        SET /A minutesSincex=60*hoursx+minutesx
        ECHO !minutesSincex!
    )
)
ENDLOCAL

EXIT /b
```

In summary, with expected vs. required:

```
SET hours=%since:~0,2%  ==> SET hours=!since:~0,2!
ECHO hours=%hours%      ==> ECHO hours=!hours!
SET hoursx=%%h          ==> SET /A hoursx=%%h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the SET its the percent expansion.
This doesn't work as you expect, it expands when the block is parsed, not when it is executed.
Therefore you should try delayed expansion.

Comment: Thanks, jeb.  Aren't I using delayed expansion already?  I thought that was what SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION did?  Could you also show me how *not* to use the % signs, as I've tried variations, but there're three different usages: %since:~3,2%, %minutesSince% and %%h - do I just replace every '%' with an '!'?

Comment: OK got it - I'll put it in an edit on the original question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I learned to avoid nested blocks and to write as short blocks as possible. Long or nested blocks are nightmare to debug and any goto in the block breaks `for` loop. So I often write a subroutine and `call:subRoutine` from which I return with `goto:eof`. The subroutine works in regular way: may alter variables and access them with `%variable%`. `Echo`, when *on*, writes actual parameters of commands. `GoTo` works as well. You pass parameters as you'd call another batch file - and a subroutine can be either separate file. Then there is no colon after the `call`.

Of course, there are still cases when using a block is handy and delayedExpansion is needed. I wanted here just to show that there is another way.